# How to repack an Java Web Archive (WAR)?

Tags: java, jar, war

I have a .war file of an application. It works, but I need to update some
inner jars *(only minor version changes)*

While I can operate on .war archives using the
midnight commander, the files can't be executed anymore:
`java.lang.SecurityException: SHA1 digest error`.

I tried repacking it using the jar command, but I get it wrong:
The archive contains new META-INF, and no WEB-INF (which is needed).

Thank you for proposed solutions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names should be `META-INF` and `WEB-INF`, without an "O".

Are you modifying the jar files in `WEB-INF/libs`? Because it sounds like you have tampered with a signed archive, and normally the war itself is unsigned.

If you alter a signed jar file, the signature is invalidated. Either re-sign the code with your code-signing key, or remove the invalidated signature information from the META-INF.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Sandly the update (in my case from ant-1.7.0 to ant-1.7.1 didn't solve the problem "dirset doesn't support the 'erroronmissingdir' attribute"). Never mind.